# Relation between eigenvectors of matrix $X^TX$ and $XX^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I found a surprising property of the eigenvectors of the matrix $A = X^T X$ and $B = XX^T$ experimentally. Let $X$ be $n \times d$ with $n > d$. Then $A$ and $B$ are psd matrices. The eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ are equal (except $B$ has additional zero eigenvalues). Take an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ and $B$, and take the corresponding eigenvector $v_A$ ($d \times 1$) and $v_B$ ($n \times 1$) of $A$ and $B$. I found that $|X v_A |\propto |v_B|$, where the absolute value is taken of each element of the vector. Is this result well known or can anybody confirm / prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\lambda \,v_A=X^TXv_A$, multiplying by $X $ on the left you get $$\lambda \,Xv_A=XX^TXv_A=BXv_A. $$ So $Xv_A $ is an eigenvector of $B $ for the eigenvalue  $\lambda $. If the multiplicity of $\lambda $ is one, then  $v_B $ is a multiple of $Xv_A $.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $B(Xv_A)=X X^T X v_A = X (A) v_A=\lambda Xv_A$ where the last equality follows from $v_A$ being an eigenvector of $A=X^TX$. Thus $Xv_A$ is an eigenvector of $B=XX^T$, so if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of multiplicity 1 then the two eigenvectors can only differ by a multiplicative constant. (If the eigenvalues of $X^T X$ are degenerate, then the two eigenvectors $Xv_A, v_B$ need not be related in this fashion.)